# Integral and limit

Tags: tag-removed, integration

During my research this integral has shown up

$ \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^T \left( 1 - \frac{|\tau|}{T}\right)e^{-\alpha\tau^2}\cos(2\pi f_0 \tau) d\tau$

I tried to solved by taking the real part of a the complex exponential but it didn't work. Any help?

Cheers,

Mikitov

Comment: already tried CAS ?

Comment: I don't think this integral can be expressed in elementary functions (which is why by the way this doesn't look like homework to me); however it is not too difficult to compute it in terms of the error function (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). If you would like more details on that, http://math.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: Yes, no homework in my life anymore...

Comment: What exactly do you want with it? It is just the convolution (up to normalization and linear change of variable) of $e^{-x^2}$ and the Fejer kernel. Of course, there is no algebraic formula (unless you consider integration by parts a.k.a. "expressing in terms of error function" a great step forward) but all *reasonable* questions shouldn't be hard to answer :). 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is 0, the integral from $0$ to $T$ is:
$$\frac{i \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{\pi ^2 f^2}{a}}
   \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  f-i a
   t}{\sqrt{a}}\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  f+i a
   t}{\sqrt{a}}\right)\right)}{4 a^{1/2}}
$$
$$
-\frac{\pi ^{3/2} f e^{-\frac{\pi ^2
   f^2}{a}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  f-i a t}{\sqrt{a}}\right)+\pi
   ^{3/2} f e^{-\frac{\pi ^2 f^2}{a}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  f+i
   a t}{\sqrt{a}}\right)-2 \pi ^{3/2} f e^{-\frac{\pi ^2 f^2}{a}}
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\pi  f}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{4ta^{3/2}}
$$
$$
+\frac{\left(1+e^{4 i \pi  f t}\right) e^{-t (a t+2 i \pi  f)}-2}{4ta},
$$
as per Mathematica.

Comment: Wow, is that hard to read.

Comment: $\lim_{T \to \infty}$ ? It does not make any sense to me for any value of alpha.

Comment: @Simon: I just pasted mathematica's TeXForm. Thank god WZ was there to fix it... @mikitov: The integral converges (for any positive alpha), so when you divide by $T$ it is not at all surprising that the limit is $0.$ 

Comment: The thing is, this integral comes from applying the necessary and sufficient conditions for a wide sense stationary process to be ergodic. The independence of alpha makes me feel nervous :-) Thank you in any case.